# Appropriate Icon for a Subscribe or Subscription

Tags: buttons, icons, symbols

What would be an appropriate Icon that could be used for **Subscribe** or **Subscription**. A subscription meaning; where a customer must pay a subscription price to have access to the product/service.

Comment: Would this icon appear instead of the word 'subscribe' or in addition to?

Comment: Would like both ways, I would like to use the subscribe icon on my admin pages as well, so will anyways require an icon alone. But yes, I would like to use it both ways.

Comment: Sorry, but icon requests are off topic for this site. There's a section specificity about this in our [FAQ] where you can get more info about why this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with having a subscribe button without the word 'subscribe' is that there is no standard icon for this.  The only subscribe icon I can think of is the RSS feed subscribe button: [image: rss icon]

which obviously wouldn't work in your case.

What you are describing sounds more like a "Join" situation.  Have a look at other companies that offer services for a monthly fee (ex: [Zipcar](http://www.zipcar.com/boston/check-rates?zipfleet_id=94396), [Adobe Creative Cloud](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativecloud.html)).

To answer your question though, there is no standard icon for this, so you should probably include the word 'Subscribe' or 'Join' wherever the button appears if you can, because it's just not something people will recognise if it's just an icon.  If appropriate you could use the shopping cart icon[image: shopping cart], but this doesn't usually make sense unless you offer multiple products, and may be confusing for something you pay monthly for.  If you happen to include an icon along with the text, and do this consistently, it may be OK to use just that icon in some places.

If this is an important call to action (if it's the way they buy your product, it should be) you need to make sure it's as clear as possible.